# How do have a single class name with a space in it using CSS

Tags: css

I have HTML like this:

```
<div class = "address full">
```

I want to add css. How do I write a selector for a class with a space in it? This is not doing waht I want.

```
."address info" {
  background: #eee;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can't - there is no way of having a space within a single classname. So the element you've provided there doesn't have a 'class name with a space in it'. The element has two different classes `address` and `full`. You can of course target this element by specifying both classes like this:

```
.address.full{}
```

If you really want 'spaces' in your class name, you'll need another way of clarifying what you see as a space, such as hyphenation:

```
<div class = "address-full">
```

Or maybe camel-case

```
<div class = "addressFull">
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't have CSS classes with spaces in them.

What you have are **two seperate classes**, `address` and `full`.

You can specify both of these in a selector as follows:

```
.address.full
{
   background: #eee;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The two words will be treated as separate classes. If they will always be used together, consider separating with a hyphen or underscore instead. However, you can target the classes using:

```
.address.info {
    background: #eee;
}
```

This is essentially identifying an element with both the class `address` and the class `info`. That is technically different from targeting a class of `address info`.

For example, if you then had a following rule applied to just `address` it would also be applied to this element.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually 2 classes: `address` and `full`

To apply a style to an element having both classes do this:

```
.address.info {
      background: #eee;
}
```

...be sure there is *no* space between the dot-separated class-names in your selector.

Answer (score 0):

A class cannot have space. It must begin with an underscore, a dash or letter. Also, a class name must be two characters long.

Use hyphen or underscore instead.

[Read this for more information.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Writing_efficient_CSS)

Comment: and cannot start with a number